# Publishing android library artifact on azure devops

Tags: azure-pipelines, android-library, azure-artifacts

I created a pipeline in azure devops which should build an artifact that i want to implement in my app , here's my pipeline :

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    tasks: 'assembleRelease'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '**/*.aar'
    targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
   targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
   artifactName: 'mypackage-Android'

- task: UniversalPackages@0
  inputs:
   command: publish
   publishDirectory: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
   vstsFeedPublish: 'proj/mypackage-Android'
   vstsFeedPackagePublish: 'com.pkg:mypackage-Android'  
   vstsPackageVersion: $(latestVersion)
```

After the pipeline runs i see the artifact in the artifact column (with the current version), but when I try to implement the library it gives me a sync error "Failed to resolve"

This are my Gradle files :

```
        maven {
        url 'https://mycomp.pkgs.visualstudio.com/proj/_packaging/mypackage-Android/maven/v1'

        credentials{
            username "testUser"
            password "token"
        }
    }
```

and:

```
    compile(group: 'com.pkg', name: 'mypackage-Android', version: '0.0.+')
```

i'm not sure where to look in order to fix it , what am I doing wrong , the pipeline or the gradle connection ?

Comment: To narrow down if this issue related to Azure DevOps Pipeline or not , suggest you first give a try with same operation in your local development environment. Did you get same error or a different result?